# Silverlight store array in file and recall later?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I can't seem to do this without using a MySQL database.

I don't know how to store an array of data (ID Codes) inside of a file and be able to recall it.

I have 4,000 unique 4 digit codes that need to be stored in an array inside of a file. The machine the silverlight app will be running on will not have internet access so I can't create a database and use http calls or anything.. it needs to be local to the project. I also am looking for a way to then take said codes and be able to test against those codes ie pass user input and validate it against the array of codes.

I've looked all over and have no idea where to begin or even how to implement it. I'm not looking for or caring about processing power or anything.. I just need functionality.

Comment: Checkout SterlingDB http://sterling.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store it in a txt file and attach the file to project as content.

the file will then be a part of the silverlight xap

read like you would read a content file.

a hashset would make perfect sense.. store however you want and load the data into hashset.. should get fastest lookups

HashSet
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Can you direct me towards some documentation on hashsets?

Comment: there you go.. added the link